# Volatile is thread safe then what is the need of AtomicInteger

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, volatile

Like AtomicInteger is thread safe as i have gone through the code and technique it uses to make it a thread safe as per the theory says

In computer science, compare-and-swap (CAS) is an atomic instruction used in multithreading to achieve synchronization. 
It compares the contents of a memory location to a given value and, only if they are the same, modifies the contents of that memory location to a given new value.
 This is done as a single atomic operation. The atomicity guarantees that the new value is calculated based on up-to-date information; if the value had been updated 
by another thread in the meantime, the write would fail. The result of the operation must indicate whether it performed the substitution; this can be done either 
with a simple Boolean response (this variant is often called compare-and-set), or by returning the value read from the memory location (not the value written to it).

I have seen the code of AtomicInteger class

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}
```

I have question that if i make a variable a thread safe just declare it volatile.therefore
all the threads reading that variable will get the latest value.
Can anybody explain me that when we have VOLATILE keyword to make the variable thread safe
then why we have the AtomicInteger class to make the variable thread safe .what is the advantage of volatile keyword over the AtomicInteger.

and if we declare volatile long and volatile double are they thread safe and if not
then why they are not thread safe. and int without volatile is thread safe. please expalin

Comment: What *language* is this? That ought to be another tag on your question.

Answer (score 5):

You have missed the really important part in AtomicInteger:

```
public final boolean compareAndSet(int expect, int update) {
    return unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(this, valueOffset, expect, update);
}
```

You can't mimic *that* in pure java with a simple volatile. Its calling to native code to perform the actual atomic *compare and set* (CAS) operation

Volatile is fine if you have *one* thread updating a field and any number of threads *reading* the field. To safely *update* the field from more than one thread you need atomic *or* synchronization.

Comment: @jameslarge volatile guarantees that writes *are* atomic, even for entities bigger than the native machine word size. (this is explained in the JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5  specifically: A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field)

Answer (score 1):

a volatile int is save to be read concurrently - but not read+write like the atomic incrementAndGet methods of the atomicInteger class.

your compare and swap would fail to synchronize if the int changed after you compare the "last good value" and you perform the actual write

Answer (score -1):

The use of VOLATILE does not make your variable thread-safe, it tells the compiler that the variable may change at any time, not necessarily by the provided code.

Comment: This is not correct statement. Volatile does make variable thread safe may be for atomic operation like increment and all you need to put some extra effort but otherwise its thread safe.

Comment: This is not correct for Java. This answer may have been posted before this was tagged "Java".